# init an object every time I open a nswindow - mac app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nswindow

I have a little stupid problem, with iPhone app I havan't this problem but with mac app yes, I want to init an object every time I open a windows, this method are called only one time:

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
- (void) windowDidLoad
- (void) awakeFromNib
```

I can init the object when I close the window but I think is a logical error:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
```

I open and close the windows in this way:

```
[tabellaController showWindow:self];
[self close];
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the code in the windowDidBecomeKey delegate method?

Comment: perfect! this work, thank you :D only a question, this method is call after outlet load, there is another method that is call before outlet load?

Answer (score 1):

- (void) windowDidBecomeKey:(NSNotification *)notification {}

this is the solution of my problem!

Comment: but this method also triggers the action when you close the NSWindow